# metodo post no angular está dando bad request 400 e webapi em c# está funcionando corretamente

Tags: html, c#, angular, formulário, asp.net-web-api

Estou criando um formulário de cadastro de produto, O submit está funcionado o problema ocorre qnd é tentado cadastrar um novo produto e quando esse novo produto tenta ser passado do formulário para a api.

Na api o método post está utilizei o swagger e está funcionado corretamente.

Na imagem do erro ao inspecionar no browser, o array de cima, na imagem, é pq foi dado um console log no que está retornando do submit e ele está me retornando o meu array de dados

ex:
id? : *number*;
nome : *string*;
imagem? : *string*;
descricao : *string*;
tipoProduto : *string*;
ativo : *boolean*;
valor : *string*;
contato : *string*;
endereco : *string*;
dataDeCriacao? :*string*;
dataDeAlteracao? : *string*;

ao inves do response.

ex:

dados: T;
mensagem: *string*;
sucesso: *boolean*;

Imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFrCE.png

O erro aponta para o cadastro component, que é o código a seguir

````
import { Produto } from '../../models/Produtos';  
import { ProdutosService } from '../../services/produtos.service';  
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  
u/Component({  
 selector: 'app-cadastro',  
 templateUrl: './cadastro.component.html',  
 styleUrls: \['./cadastro.component.css'\]  
})  
/\*\*  
 \*  
 \*/  
export *class* CadastroComponent {  
 *constructor*(private *produtoService* : ProdutosService, private *router* : Router) {  
   
   
  }  
   
 createProduto(*produto* : Produto){  
   
 this.produtoService.CreateProduto(*produto*).subscribe(()*=>*{  
 this.router.navigate(\['/'\])  
})  
}  
  } ```
````

Comment: Considerando que [esta pergunta já foi feita antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/590941/70) e orientações já foram dadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado para evitar duplicidade de informações (mas pode ser usado na questão original).